# Go to content with anchor after some time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anchor

I have an "intro image" on my site that the user can clic and will scroll down the page to the content, using an anchor. Well, not everyone clics on the link so I want that the page scrolls down to the content automatically after some seconds (if the user didn't clic already the anchor-link). Is there any way using JS or CSS that could help me do that?

Here's the link http://www.bahelitours.com/es/info-test

Comment: `setTimeout()` combined with some nice css `transition`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The target area is `#info-content`. Use `setTimeout()` to run after some time (this runs at 5000ms, or 5s - change that as you see fit), and see if the user hasn't scrolled (`$.scrollTop() == 0`), and if they haven't, scroll to the target area.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0) {
    $('html, body').animate({
  scrollTop: $('#info-content').offset().top
    },500,"swing");
  }
},5000);
```

```css
header,#info-content {
  height: 300vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header></header>
<section id="info-content">info-content</section>
```

Comment: Ok thanks @michael-coker looks like this is what I need, however I am newie with javascript. I tried to use your code on the page but it didn't work :( any suggestion?

Comment: @Phil yeah, remove `header,#info-content {
  height: 300vh;
}` that's CSS and you don't need that - that was just for my example.

Comment: @Micheal this is awesome and worked perfectly! Many thanks mate :)

Comment: @Phil sweet, you bet :)